# Get only visible text within an html element and child elements

Tags: javascript

I have the following html:

```
<td>
  <strong>CLERK SHALL ISSUE THE CERTIFICATE OF TITLE</strong>
  <!-- DUE DATE & COMPLETED DATE -->
  <div class="SmallNotes" hidden="hidden">
    <i>Due Date:&nbsp;</i><br>
    <i>Complete Date:&nbsp;</i><br>
  </div>
  <!-- PARTY NAME -->
  <div class="SmallNotes" hidden="hidden">
    <i></i><br>
  </div>
</td>
```

I just want to get the text that is visible in the browser, which in this case is:

```
CLERK SHALL ISSUE THE CERTIFICATE OF TITLE
```

Now sometimes the divs will not have hidden attributes and will therefore be visible on screen.

My immediate solution is innerText:

```
cells[6].innerText
> "CLERK SHALL ISSUE THE CERTIFICATE OF TITLE"
```

However, I run this in a casperjs script and sometimes it picks up the  `Due Date:` text as well, which should have been hidden. As a result, innerText is not reliable when running inside casperjs. Is there another method to get only the visible text? The jQuery text() method produces all text, including hidden text. innerHTML produces html elements. textContent() works the same way as jQuery's text(). Also, note that sometimes the text will appear directly within the td tags.

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario specifically; assuming all the children are a direct (1st level) which could have the 'hidden' attribute, are a descendant of the  element, you can simply loop through all the children and check for a 'hidden' attribute:

```
Array.from(cells[6].children).map(el => 
    el.getAttribute('hidden') ? '' : el.innerText
).join('');
```

Similarly, if you want to do this over children of the element, you can do something resursively such as:

```
var loop = function(el) {
    var out = [];

    if(el.getAttribute('hidden')) return;

    if(el.children.length > 0) 
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < el.children.length; ++i) out.push(loop(el.children[i]));
    } 
    else 
    {
        out.push(el.innerText);
    }
    return out.join(' ');
};

loop(cells[6]);
```

Comment: In my question, I also had this: Also, note that sometimes the text will appear directly within the td tags and not be children

Answer (score 1):

You will need to traverse through all the child Nodes to check if they have the hidden attribute. Here is solution below using JQuery

```
   var $childNodes = $("td").children();
   console.log($childNodes.filter(':visible').text());
```

Comment: In my question, I also had this: Also, note that sometimes the text will appear directly within the td tags and not be children

Comment: the above solution will work even If there is text directly without any wrapper html tag. if you want to traverse through all the childNodes then you can use document.getElementById("idname").childNodes  to get all the childNodes