# How do I get only the visible children elements of a parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried:

```
var $childNodes = $(".definition").children();
console.log($childNodes.filter(':visible').text());
```

from [Get only visible text within an html element and child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690611/get-only-visible-text-within-an-html-element-and-child-elements)
and I'm getting back all the elements from the parent element with a `visibility` set to `hidden` instead of `visible`.

The full code is on [repl preview panel](https://repl.it/@MathewStratton1/AnotherDecisiveEyestrain#index.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**:visible** works for **display** not for **visibility**, because visibility consumes space in layout, also **opacity** too.

```js
$(".definition").children().filter(function(){ return $(this).css("visibility")=="visible"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="definition">
     
  <div style= "visibility:hidden" class="definitionAgelenidae">Family:Agelenidae:Definition</div>
    <div style= "visibility:visible" class="definitionYorimaGenus">Genus:Yorima:Definition</div>
    <div style= "visibility:hidden" class="definitionYorima_angelica">Yorima angelica Roth:Definition</div>
    <div style= "visibility:hidden" class="definitionCybaeusGenus">Genus: Cybaeus:Definition</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/zZyjc1x https://ibb.co/HD5nJ6r This is still bringing in all the elements that are hidden

Comment: I think you're right, although every element in the list is set to hidden. How could I convert your snippet to an if statement as to check the visibility of every child element onclick

Comment: if($(".definition").children().filter(function(){ return $(this).css("visibility")=="visible"})){document.querySelector("#spiderInject").innerHTML=$(".definition").children().filter(function(){ return $(this).css("visibility")=="visible"})}     ??

Comment: you mean, when the definition div clicked, you want to check children's visibility?

Comment: The issue now is getting the innerhtml of the black definition box to transfer to the input form but only if it becomes visible from the onclick of the spiderpicker tile in the top right hand corner https://ibb.co/68sC6sM

Comment: var Test02;
setInterval(function(){Test02= $(".definition").children().filter(function(){ return $(this).css("visibility")=="visible"});console.log(Test02);if(Test02.length>=1){$(".spiderInject").value=Test02}},5000)

Comment: I figured this would work but I couldn't get the data to go to the input in the form, in the console the length is greater than one so I guess I'm measuring the length of the wrong object?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".definition").children().filter(function(index, ele){return $(ele).is(":visible")})
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/JtNLJ4Y https://ibb.co/v1YszLV This returned all the elements. what kind of object is this, how could I put this into an array if it were bringing in the right elements, i.e. just the visible elements?